# flutter) I want to know how to drag & draw shapes through Custom Paint

Tags: flutter, paint

I'm making a whiteboard app.

I learned how to draw lines using GestureDetector() and CustomPaint(). Now I'm going to draw the shapes, but I don't know how to draw the location and size of the shape by touching and dragging them after selecting the shape tool.

The image below is an example of another whiteboard app.

Can you tell me how to draw by dragging the shape as below?

[image]

Comment: Could the `Draggable` widget be of any help?

Comment: I'm kinda confused.. if you can use the `GestureDetector` to draw straight lines, surely drawing rectangles instead is almost identical in terms of code and functionality?

Comment: I actually have the similar design to create. Are you able to complete this?